# How to change APP content in android but not need to update your soft version

Tags: android

I'm new for android.I want to make an APP change my content everyday, but I don't think my user will like to update my APP everyday.

How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You could make an HTTP request to download your new daily content from a web server. Check out [HttpUriRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html):

> Extended version of the HttpRequest
>   interface that provides convenience
>   methods to access request properties
>   such as request URI and method type.

Comment: Thanks for you so soon answer, I will try it. And will tell you where I get.

Comment: @AnothrWu No problem. Good luck with it.